# Insert/update loop ORACLE function

Tags: oracle, insert, bulk-insert, merge

I want to find the best solution for an insert/update oracle function. My task is to collect some date from multiple tables (source tables) and bring them to a single table (destination table). Source tables getting inserts and updates in real time. My function must run ones/day to getting all new data and updated data to destination table. I identify my new / updated data by using a column (date) from source table based on a trigger witch update the date column with systimestamp at every insert/update.
My current code looks like this

```
for rec in (
select firstname, lastname, email, id
      from people_source 
where people_source.date > last_run_date
)

loop

merge into people_destionation dest
  using ( select firstname, lastname, email, id from dual ) src
  on (src.id=dest.id)
 when matched then updated set
 firstname=src.firstname,
 lastname=src.lastname,
 email=src.email
when not matched then
insert
(
firstname,
lastname,
email,
id
)
values 
(
rec.firstname,
rec.lastname,
rec.email,
rec.id
);

exception when others ....
```

This solution make what I want, but I tested for 100k rows. I have source tables with 100 mil. rows and I try to find the best performance solution.
I also read about "Switching between PL/SQL and SQL engines" and I think this applies to me. Will it be a better idea to try to make functions with BULK COLLECT and FORALL?

I have not a very long experience in pl/sql, so I need more opinions and I thing here is a good place. Thanks. Best wishes.

Comment: BUG DETECTED - Unless you have a `RAISE`/`RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` in your `WHEN OTHERS` clause, you have a bug.  PS - why are you looping? You can do that in a single `MERGE` statement

Comment: Yes I have, all errors goes into a error table. Hmm, I did the loop because I want to take only the new/updated rows from source. Does it work without a loop?

Comment: Instead of trying to create your own procedures/tables, this sounds like a textbook case for a Materialized View.

Comment: I thought about this, but I need tables for this, because this data are going in other databases and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are issueing one SQL statement for every row you get from your `people_source` table. This is called row-by-row (read **slow-by-slow**) processing. For every query you make you force a context switch from PL/SQL to SQL engine and back which will add up pretty quickly.

As a first step, you should try to implement the functionality using just SQL (in this way, you eliminate expensive SQL/PLSQL context switch altogether). Try to use the `merge` DML as it was meant to be used:

```
merge into people_destionation dest
using (
  select firstname, lastname, email, id
    from people_source 
   where people_source.date > last_run_date
) src on (src.id = dest.id)
when matched then
  updated set firstname = src.firstname,
              lastname = src.lastname,
              email = src.email
when not matched then
  insert (firstname, lastname, email, id)
  values (src.firstname, src.lastname, src.email, src.id)
```

In case this is slow, then we need more information (for example how many rows you expect to be merged, how are source/target tables created, are there any triggers, indexes) to be able to propose a way to make it faster (adding index on Id column, parallel execution, partitioning the table, eliminating triggers, disabling/recreating indexes, ...).